# Sticky Navigation Bar / Right of a Centered Div

Tags: javascript, navigation, fixed, sidebar, sticky

I am editing a Squarespace template and would like to create a sticky navigation sidebar.
There's a Squarespace field where I can enter "Custom CSS."

I already have the sidebar, but how do I modify the CSS to make it stick? I want it to remain visible when I scroll below the fold.

My `pageBodyWrapper` div is centered (auto/auto) and contains both the `contentWrapper` div and the `sidebar1Wrapper` div, on the right.

I have tried

```
#sidebar1Wrapper 
{
   position:fixed;
}
```

with either a left or right value in `px` or `%`, but whenever I change window size, the sidebar  is either going away from the content or overlaps with it.

How do I prevent this from happening?
Can I define my fixed position relative to the `contentWrapper` div?

Thank you for your help!

Here's the site I am talking about: [Last Wave Film](http://lastwavefilm.com).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that functionality is not yet built into css. It is done with javascript. Essentially the javascript detects when the page has scrolled to the top of and then sets the sidebar to `position: fixed`.

Here's a solution that uses the jQuery library: http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/

You can make the sidebar fixed using css and it will be permanently fixed within the browser window.

```
.sidebar1Wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   top: 20px;
   right: 40px;
}
```